# Import не видит папку

Tags: python

В корне лежит несколько репозиториев и исполняемый файл run.py.
Некоторые репы мои, некоторые нет и содержат сложную структуру, встречаются __init__, __main__ файлы. Я запускаю свой скрипт и получаю после цепочки import вызовов эту проблему:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named repository_1/src
Но если в этой же консоли откуда я запускаю, вывести файлы, папки на месте. 
Все import в цепочке написаны мною и пути даже в одной репе начинаются с корня. Я не уверен, что так правильно, но я не знаю способа лучше без sys.path.append
Т.е. в my_rep/src/scripts/say_hello.py все импорты написаны в духе\

```
from my_rep/src/utils/utils.py import hello_func
from my_rep_old/src/utils/utils.py import hello_func_old
```

И они поднимаются нормально. Но один из импортов не в мою репу падает.

Comment: Импорты никак не могут быть написаны в таком духе, потому что это синтаксически некорректный код. Вы что-то не договариваете. Составьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в папку `my_rep` файл `__init__.py`

Файлы `__init__.py` необходимы, чтобы Python рассматривал каталоги как содержащие пакеты; это делается для того, чтобы предотвратить каталоги с общим именем, например string, от непреднамеренного скрытия допустимых модулей, которые происходят позже (глубже) на пути поиска модуля. В простейшем случае `__init__.py` может быть просто пустым файлом, но он также может выполнять код инициализации для пакета или устанавливать переменную `__all__`, описанную ниже.

```
package_x/
|--  __init__.py
|--    subPackage_a/
|------  __init__.py
|------  module_m1.py
|--    subPackage_b/
|------  __init__.py
|------  module_n1.py
|------  module_n2.py
|------  module_n3.py
```

Мы можем использовать `__init__.py` в `subPackage_b` для ограничения импортируемых модулей следующим образом:

```
__all__ = ['module_n2', 'module_n3']
```

После запуска:

```
>>>from package_x.subPackage_b import * 
>>>module_n1.function_X()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named module_n1
```