# Не работает импорт в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется такая структура:

```
- /dir/file1.py
- /dir/file2.py
- main.py
- main2.py
```

В `file1.py` стоит импорт:

```
from file2 import module
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'
```

Пытался так:

```
from dir.file2 import module
```

Получаю:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Как тут быть?
Есть подозрение, что `sys.path.append` сработает, если добавить его в `file1.py`, но выглядит не очень - писать его в каждый файл.

**Вопросов два:**

- Поможет ли `sys.path.append`?
- Как принято решать такие ситуации?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Import не видит папку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1244418/import-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: [Вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) больше подходит

Comment: Сделал `__init__.py`, вписал в `__all__: [file2]`. Не работает, та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

В file1 можно написать

```
from .file2 import module
```

Работает,
но тогда запуск file1 напрямую падает.
Это решается запуском с флагом `-m` вашего модуля. Например

```
python -m dir.file1
```